# Selenium Python >> get a value of an attribute from the console log of the webpage

Tags: python, selenium

How do we get a value of an attribute from the console log of the webpage?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v991z.png) For example in the screenshot (link above) I have highlighted the following:

page_renderer: "articleRenderer"

When the webpage loads I would like to verify if the value for page_renderer is "articleRenderer" or if it is "articleRenderer2".

Could you please let me know? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the page url so that DOM can be check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot:

```
page_renderer_value = driver.execute_script('return rtech.visitor.page_renderer')
```

Comment: @chauhany Can you share the error, please?

Comment: sorry my bad..it worked. I get what I needed. Thank you so much Max Daroshchanka